# Apache Flink and Kafka Stream Benchmarking

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, benchmarking

### What I'm trying to do

For a university project i am are trying to compare Apache Flink and Apache Kafka Streaming Performance (Throughput, Latency) using different configurations (1 Nodes, 2 Nodes, 4 Nodes, changing amount of CPU cores etc.).

For this purpose i have created a twitter JSON dataset containing ~ 15.000 Tweets, each tweet delimited by a newline.

### The Problem

As far as i know `Kafka` follows the pattern "Producer - Kafka Cluster/Brokers - Consumer" and, for benchmarking the latency, i would measure the time between Producer and Consumer for each record.

The problem is, as far as i can tell `Apache Flink` lacks the ability of the Producer pattern - it seems like i have to specify a `source` for the data stream which the `TaskManagers` ("Consumers") would then fetch and process.

This makes it hard for me to tell how i should benchmark both systems in a comparable way because, for the **latency** measurement, i would measure the time between **Producer** and **Consumer** whereas in `Flink` i would have to measure the time between the `JobManager` and `TaskManagers`. So the producer part would be missing here.

Assuming i haven't misunderstood something, how would i measure both systems in a comparable way in order to make reasonable judgements?

Answer (score 2):

What you could do with Flink would be to build this pipeline:

```
event generator -> input topic -> flink job -> output topic -> analysis
```

I would configure both Kafka producers (the one in the event generator and the one in Flink) to use log-append timestamps. And I would arrange for the flink job to copy the incoming timestamps to a field of the corresponding output records so that what gets written to the output topic are events that have two timestamps: one generated by the kafka broker for the input partition, and the other generated by the broker handling the output partition. I would further arrange it so that the same broker is used in both cases, so that the timestamps are clearly comparable.

You should be able to do pretty much the same thing for Kafka Streaming.

BTW, 15000 tweets will flow through this way too quickly to get meaningful results. I recommend implementing an event generator that that can pump out arbitrarily long event streams.

Comment: As far as i know the LogAppend Timestamp is the timestamp where kafka stores the record in the topic. Is there a way to append a timestamp when Kafka sends the record to the Consumer? This would make it possible to measure the latency when Producer and Consumer are not running at the same time

Comment: I don’t believe that’s possible.

Comment: Okay, i guess i will have to have both of them running at the same time then. The reason i wanted to avoid this is because the requirement of the project is that everything has to be reproducible in jupyter notebooks and using one notebook is more convenient than two obviously. Anyway, thank you for helping

Comment: We tried to do what you suggested and we're getting weird latencies. We are doing it slightly different tho: Instead of using two timestamps, we just send the latency as message value back to kafka into another topic. In the Flink Job, we use FlinkKafkaConsumer and FlinkKafkaProducer with `SimpleStringSchema` and a custom `ProcessFunction`, where the latency is computed with `(time.time() * 1000) - ctx.timestamp()`. Latencies are > 1000 ms. To investigate, we tried with producing single messages: In Kafka 1-3ms, in Flink we get 200ms - 700ms. We use 10 vCPU, 40 GB RAM. Any tip?

Comment: You can take a look at the flink job code here [link](https://github.com/Manu10744/Stream-Analytics/blob/master/flink/flink_stream.ipynb)

Comment: You shouldn't expect to get great performance with pyflink, since there is overhead in making the connection between the JVM and Python.